# How to execute several maven deploy commands on the same process

Tags: java, performance, maven, process, nexus

I am trying to develop a tool that get a directory of maven artifacts and upload them to Nexus 3. The tool is working but I have a performance issue.
My program launch a separate maven process for each artifact that must be uploaded.I'm curious whether these could be batched somehow.

I am using the `maven-invoker` library for executing maven commands.

```
public class MavenUploader {

private final MavenDeployer mavenDeployer;

@Inject
public MavenUploader(MavenDeployer mavenDeployer) {
    this.mavenDeployer = mavenDeployer;
}

@Override
public void uploadToRepository(Path pathToUpload) {
    try (Stream<Path> files = Files.walk(pathToUpload)){
        files.forEach(mavenDeployer::deployArtifact);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

This is the class that resposible to upload the artifacts

```
import org.apache.maven.shared.invoker.*;

public class MavenDeployer {

private final InvocationRequest invocationRequest;
private final Invoker invoker;

@Inject
public MavenDeployer(InvocationRequest invocationRequest,                   
                     Invoker invoker) {
    this.invocationRequest = invocationRequest;
    this.invoker = invoker;
}

public void deployArtifact(Path pathToPom, String commandToExecute) {
    invocationRequest.setGoals(Collections.singletonList(commandToExecute));
    InvocationResult invocationResult = invoker.execute(invocationRequest);
}
```

for each time that the `deployArtifact` method called new process is opened, There is a way to batch all the uploads to use the same process?

Comment: Don't think so, however you can use http requests https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/115006744008

Answer (score 0):

Not maven-deploy but you can use this if you'd like: https://github.com/DarthHater/nexus-repository-import-scripts

I think it accomplishes what you want to do.